# Specifying a different 'Executed Function' than 'Name' in GCP cloudbuild.yaml

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

How do I specify a different "Executed Function" in my cloudbuild.yaml file than the name of the actual function name in GCP?

For example:

- I have a cloud function, written in python called `hello_world`
- In my GCP deployment, I want to name the function `hello-world-dev`, and `hello-world-prod` which is passed in the Triggers variables dynamically on build.
- Build fails because it was expecting the function to be called `hello-world-dev` or whatever
- I'm sure there's a flag to specify the executing function, but I haven't found it.

My `cloudbuild.yaml` file looks like this:

```
#hello-world
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    args:
      - gcloud
      - functions
      - deploy
      - hello-world-${_ENV}
      - --region=us-west2
      - --source=./demo/hello-world/
      - --trigger-http
      - --runtime=python39
```

**Steps I've Tried**

I've tried the following flags:

- `--function`
- `--call`
- `--deploy`

Looking at this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The executed function is the function name in your code. By default, and it's your error, the executed function, if not specified, must be the same as the function name.

If your function name has a different name as the executed function, you need to specify the entrypoint of your function (the function to run in your code). Use the parameter `--entry-point=`